# How to not override AWS desired_count with Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm managing an autoscaling cloud infrastructure in AWS.

Every time I run Terraform it wants to override the `desired_count`, i.e. the number of running instances.

I would like this to not happen. How do I do that?

Constraints: I manage multiple different microservices, each of which set up their running instances with a shared module, where `desired_count` is specified. I don't want to change the shared module such that `desired_count` is ignored for *all* my microservices. Rather, I want to be able to override or not on a service-by-service (i.e caller-by-caller) basis.

This rules out a straightforward use of `lifecycle { ignore_changes = ... }`. As far as I can tell, the list of changes to ignore cannot be given as arguments (my Terraform complains when I try; feel free to tell me how you succeed at this).

My next idea (if possible) is to read the value from the stored state, if present, and ask for a `desired_count` equal to its current value, or my chosen initial value if it has no current value. If there are no concurrent Terraform runs (i.e. no races), this should accomplish the same thing. Is this possible?

I'm no expert terraformer. I would appreciate it a lot if you give very detailed answers.

Comment: Is it not possible to pass a variable / local to `ignore_changes` and that variable is either `[]` or `[desired_count]` depending on some outer variable like `should_ignore_desired_count`!?

Comment: @luk2302: if so you'll have to spell out the exact syntax for me

Comment: Add a variable `variable "should_ignore_desired_count" {default=false}` to your module, and then specify a `lifecycle { ignore_changes = var.should_ignore_desired_count ? [desired_count] : [] }` on your resource - not sure if this works.

Comment: Can you possibly show an example of what you have now and then explain how you'd like some to have desired count managed by Terraform and others to be managed separately (eg out of band scaling or application autoscaling) and how you'd differentiate between those? Ideally this should be in the form of a [mcve] if you can to simplify it but get enough context across.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR: that's a very reasonable request. With my current terraforming skills, I don't think my boss will let me perform that simplification process, not even to our test environment, nor grant me the budget to run enough experiments on a fresh account. And even though there might not be any magic sauce in there, I'm not happy sharing company property on SO. Besides, I think that if my problem can be solved at all, it can be solved at a high level of generality in a way that works across many contexts, so do you really need mine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifecycle parameters affect how the graph is built, so they can't be parameterized. The terraform team hasn't ruled out that this could be implemented, but they haven't done it with the issue reported over a couple years.

What you could do is create two `aws_ecs_service` resources, and switch between them:

```
resource "aws_ecs_service" "service" {
    count = var.use_lifecycle ? 0 : 1
    ...
}

resource "aws_ecs_service" "service_with_lifecycle" {
    count = var.use_lifecycle ? 1 : 0
    ...
    lifecycle {
        ignore_changes = ["desired_count"]
    }
}
```

Given that, you need a way to reference the service you created. You can do that with a local:

```
locals {
    service = var.use_lifecycle ? aws_ecs_service.service_with_lifecycle[0] : aws_ecs_service.service[0]
}
```

Comment: I thought of that as well, but discarded it because it seems to (a) involve terraform code duplication between the resource blocks; and (b) scale exponentially in the number of changes I want to ignore. The general pattern here is hard-code all the "data constants" (resource blocks) into my terraform files, then use a variable to select the one I want, rather than computing the result I want. I guess that's the best that can be done? But ugh, there's a reason we compute rather than tabulate e.g. byte addition (well, most of the time anyways).

Comment: Sounds like it might be a job for good old development-time code generation.